# In what sense do we mean 'distributed' when talking about a distributed representation of words?

Tags: terminology, machine-learning

In machine learning literature, when handling words or text inputs, the strings are often mapped onto a vector space using techniques such as word2vec.

The terminology in this is that the individual word vectors are 'embeddings' and the embeddings together are a distributed representation of the input words (see reference to this use in the [original word2vec paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781)).

What does 'distributed' mean in this case? I have been assuming that the transformed words are distributed in the vector space of the codomain, is this correct?

Comment: From a similar question on Quora, it would seem that distributed means that the values in the word vector are distributed throughout the dimensions and not just in one dimension, as would be the case with a one-hot vector representation of a word. https://www.quora.com/Deep-Learning-What-is-meant-by-a-distributed-representation